# Cleanup TestManagement Database - Stopped result

Tags: tfs

I'm using team foundation server 2012 Update 2 and in the TFS montoring history all the jobs for the 'Cleanup TestManagement Database' have a result of stopped. In a single evening i am getting up to 12 entries in the job history and run times are always just a few seconds. Is this normal behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use test management? Is there any error message in event log?

Comment: Hello, Yes we do and there isn't anything of great interest in the eventlog just some warnings regarding requests taking longer than 30 seconds but not failing.

Comment: Will you get stop result when the test management is used?

Comment: Not necessarily it happens through the night when the server is pretty much idle.